# @Html.DropDownListFor get ID and value into model along with differing names for ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Can anyone help on how to do this please?

I have a model

```
Product{ID, Name, SupplierID, Supplier}
Supplier {ID, Name}
```

using a `@Html.DropDownListFor` I would like to populate both the `SupplierID` and the `Supplier` of the product

in the ProductController I use

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
    Product product = db.products.Find(id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.SupplierId = new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "ID", "Name", product.SupplierID );
    return View(customer);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Customer customer)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

In `db.SaveChanges` it complains that `Supplier` is `NULL` using a view with 
(model => model.SupplierID, ViewBag.SupplierId as SelectList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use jquery for this.  Add selected name to your model and assign it to a hidden field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedName, new { @class = "SelectedName" })
```

then in your script

```
$('#SupplierID").on('change', function(){
    $('.SelectedName').val($('#SupplierID :selected').text());
});
```

So every time you change the drop down the selected name gets put in the hidden field and that will get passed back to the controller along with the selected id from the dropdown.  Hopefully this helps

Comment: Interestingly enough it put the whole list in the hidden field.  But getting there, now just have to sort out the default selection as it appears as one list has ID and one SupplierID it does not select.

Comment: I replaced this with a selected tag.  Try that

Comment: if this answer helped solve your problem would you mind checking my answer as the correct one?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I had to leave it for a while and only just manged to get back to it, the selected worked wonderfully thank you.  Would you know how to fix the default problem?

Comment: what is the default problem?  If it is setting a default for the drop down then that is an option in the dropdown list @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Supplier, SelectList, "Default"),  don't remember if it is the 3rd or the 4th item

Comment: All sorted, dont have the viewbag variable name the same as the name of the element in the view.  For some reason that stopped the default selected from working., cnaged the viewbag variable name and it worked.